# How to add CCQWP programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, visual-studio, content-query-web-part

I need to add the Content Query Web Part programmatically in SharePoint 2010. I exactly don't know how to do that. I searched over the internet but not find the exact post anywhere. I got [this](http://sharepointnista.blogspot.in/2010/03/add-custom-content-query-web-part.html) post. But I want elaborate post or step wise suggestion.

Please give any suggestion or links to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is an example of how to add webpart to a page programmatically:

```
SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost/sites/MyNewSite");
SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Shared Documents/MyPage1.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);

//Create an instance of Custom Webpart and add in a Webpart zone
CQWP wp = new CQWP(); // the cqwp webpart correct instance
wp.Title = "My WebPart Using OM";   // set properties


webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Left", 0);
webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
```

I hope this will help a little bit.

Comment: I am not finding any property of `wp` object, is there any thing wrong?

Comment: My code line is `ContentByQueryWebPart wp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();` but when I try to access the `Title` property it is not displaying..

Comment: normally i shoul dhave the access to the title property. Try to add a using Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.WebControls;

Comment: I want to configure the web part, i.e. give list name, set item style etc.. If there any reference the plz suggest.. @Shkipper

Comment: I would say explare all the properties of the webpart when you instantiate it and set those that  you would like to: wp.ItemStyle (which accpets string, so i suppose you can pass there a style) or wp.ListName or wp.ListGuid to set the list, for all overview of the properties check: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.contentbyquerywebpart_properties(v=office.14).aspx